# Parabola properties assumptions

Tags: conic-sections, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to model projectile trajectory but I'm having some trouble. I didn't realise parabolas are this complicated...

I have some assumptions that I would like to be clarified.

1. If I specify a starting point and an ending point for a throw, the apex of the throw must be higher than the starting and ending positions in order for the path to be modeled as a parabola.
2. As long as the apex is higher than the starting and ending positions' height, the apex can be anywhere between the starting and ending positions as long as it lies on the same plane as them.

Are these assumptions correct?

EDIT: This diagram shows that in my case, the maxima doesnt have to be perfectly in between the start and ending positions. It is true for the red points but not true for the green points.

[image]

Comment: The maxima has to always lie in exactly the between of the points (assuming they lie on the ground) as a parabola is always symmetrical about it's axis. Furthermore, there always has to be a maxima between the two points (by Rolle's theorem)

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: You are assumptions are true then. There might not even be a maxima in this case. But note this, the maxima can never lie exactly above the points. Also, any kind of projectile motion always results in a parabola

Comment: I still don't think my assumptions are correct. Imagine that my starting point is the left green dot, my ending point is the right red dot and my apex is a little bit above the left red dot. You cannot fix a parabola to those points eventhough my assumptions are met.

Comment: I meant to say they are correct, but only partially. I posted an answer clarifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are half correct. Here's why:

1. The apex can never be lower than the higher point of the starting and endpoints, The best you can get is, the highest point of the two (start or end) itself will become the apex.
2. You can always define a vertical parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ passing through $3$ given points. Just substitute the points' coordinates in the equation and solve for $a,b,c$. However, no $2$ points should have the same ordinate and all the three points cannot have the same abscissa as the projectile will have to have $0$ horizontal velocity in the first case, and infinite in the latter.

*Note: After an answer is acquired, confirm that it is concave downwards. If not, the parabola for projectile motion cannot be defined with the given points.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm am still confused as to how to check. I am given the start end and apex and I need to be able to determine if a parabola can be fit to those points or not.

Comment: @Ogen Substitute the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of apex, start and end in $y=ax^2+bx+c$. You will have $3$ equations in terms of $a,b,c$. Solve for $a,b,c$. Confirm that the parabola is concave downwards by evaluating the sign of $a$. If $a<0$, then the parabola can be defined for projectile motion.